# get_query_var('paged') giving same result

Tags: pagination, query, wpdb

I have a custom page, in that page i am using a custom select query for my search functionality.

The problem is  pagination  not working. I used `$on_page= get_query_var('paged');` for pagination. When I echo  `$on_page`, it always return 0 as the result. I am using a custom theme (soundwaves) for my site.

This is my query:

```
$resultsTotal = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT p.post_title,p.ID,pm.meta_value 
        FROM wp_posts p 
        join wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id 
        WHERE  pm.meta_value 
                LIKE '%$track%' AND (p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status='publish')  
        GROUP BY p.ID"
);
```

Comment: Please take a look at [`like_escape()`](http://queryposts.com/function/like_escape/) and [tag:meta-query].

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. As is, I can't see why you need a custom SQL query at all.